# Getting test: too many arguments error while checking existence of directory in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I am trying to write a shell script for extraction of `.tar.gz` file. I need to check first that if same directory is not present then extract the `zip` file. Otherwise do some thing else. Below is my shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash


INSTALL_DIR=$HOME/Test/LogShipper
LOGSTASH_PATH=logstash-2.3.2
LOGSTASH_FOLDER=$HOME/Test/LogShipper/logstash
LOGSTASH_BINARY=$LOGSTASH_PATH.tar.gz
ES_PATH=elasticsearch-2.3.2
ES_BINARY=$ES_PATH.tar.gz
KIBANA_VERSION=kibana-4.5.0
KIBANA_OS=darwin-x64
KIBANA_BINARY=$KIBANA_VERSION-$KIBANA_OS

echo Installing ELK stack into $INSTALL_DIR
mkdir -p $INSTALL_DIR

cd $INSTALL_DIR

if test [! -d "$LOGSTASH_FOLDER" ];
then
    if test -s $LOGSTASH_BINARY
    then
        echo Logstash Zip Exists
        echo Now installing...
        echo Unpacking logstash...
        tar zxf $LOGSTASH_BINARY $LOGSTASH_FOLDER
        echo Unpacking Completed.
    else
        echo Downloading logstash 2.3.2
        curl -O https://download.elasticsearch.org/logstash/logstash/$LOGSTASH_BINARY
    fi
else
        echo Logstash already installed.
fi
```

I am getting error `test: too many arguments` at line  `if test [! -d "$LOGSTASH_FOLDER" ];`

Comment: need a space after the first `[`. Also you don't need test before `[]` as `[]` is test....

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have tried but getting same error. Should I update the question with space?

Comment: Thanks I removed "test" phrase and now it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't need to use `test` when using `[]` as it implicitly invokes the same during evaluation. Also include a `space` after open brace `[`.

```
if [ ! -d "$LOGSTASH_FOLDER" ];
```

You can explicitly use `test` command the following way, try

```
if ! test  -d "$LOGSTASH_FOLDER"
```

Answer (score 0):

If "$HOME" has any spaces in it, and were unquoted (as it is in the given code), that would cause the error in question.  Suggest changing:

```
INSTALL_DIR=$HOME/Test/LogShipper
...
LOGSTASH_FOLDER=$HOME/Test/LogShipper/logstash
...
mkdir -p $INSTALL_DIR
...
cd $INSTALL_DIR
```

To:

```
INSTALL_DIR="$HOME"/Test/LogShipper
...
LOGSTASH_FOLDER="$HOME"/Test/LogShipper/logstash
...
mkdir -p "$INSTALL_DIR"
...
cd "$INSTALL_DIR"
```